# How to connect another one remote branch to the commit tree

Tags: git, branch, tortoisegit

I have a commit tree with remote branches. Recently I've got a requirement to push changes from my `master` branch to another remote branch `origin_fsa/master`.

I added new remote `origin_fsa` and fetched the remote branch from that remote and now it goes separate from the main commit graph. Like this (I use TortoiseGit):

[image]

I want to re-write everything on this newly added remote with my specific commit (no need to merge, no need to keep those commits on `origin_fas/master` remote branch, maybe just hard rebase). But I don't know how to do it.

I want the `origin_fsa/master` remote branch (blue line) to be on my current master on the picture.

Comment: It will probably help avoid confusion - both for yourself and when trying to communicate git issues with others - to clarify a bit of terminology.  What you describe is not a "hard rebase".  A rebase is the creation of new commits from old commits, such that the new commits apply the same changes from a different commit, and/or in a different order, and/or with some commits "squashed" and/or dropped; it is not "hard" or "soft", it just is.  A reset can be hard, and for a local branch that would be what you're doing.  For a remote branch, you force push to move to an arbitrary commit

Comment: I used "hard rebase" to describe my wish not to merge anything but just write changes over the previous commits. Thank you for explanation on these terms, @MarkAdelsberger!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To force push your local `master` branch to the `master` branch located on `origin_fsa` :

```
git push -f origin_fsa master:master
```

Comment: Be aware of that the force push may lose some commits on remote "origin_fsa" if you don't merge/rebase first.

Answer (score 1):

By using TortoiseGit:

[image]

As you can see, it's:

> push local branch "master"
>       to the remote branch "master"
>       on remote "origin_fsa"
>       with force (actually, it's "--force-with-lease" git option)

**Be aware of that the force push may lose some commits on remote "origin_fsa" if you don't merge/rebase first.**

Also see the tips of the **know changes** and **unknown changes** options:
[image]
[image]
(These tips will show up when moving the mouse on those options)

I'd recommend using **known changes** option first.

---

If not using force option, you may encounter this error:

```
git.exe push --progress "origin_fsa" master:master

To XXX/fsa.git
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'XXX/fsa.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation! But I didn't check my changes when I force-pushed my changes to the new remote. In fact I overwrote the remote with my local master.
IN FACT I wanted to save the history of the remote and create new commit that would've had files from my local master. Fortunately, remote is not important and it's okay that I overwrote the history but I wanted to find out how I could do what I described.